# life cycle in .net maui app for heavy operation

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have to load a list from local database when screen get visible,
Where(lifecycle) should I call my data loading function? I tried calling it on separate thread but that's also slowing down page navigation.

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        LoadPendingListFromLocalDb();//<--My function for data loading
    }
```

Getting this exception when coming back from another screen , issue is on rendering list-data, db operation running fine.

```
    System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer'.'
```

Comment: If you use the frame in your page.xaml. I suggest you use the Border instead of Frame. The official document said:  **The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement.**

Comment: This seems like two questions in one. Please make sure to focus on a single problem per question. About the first question, if you're asking for recommendations, then it's off-topic. As a general note, you should do heavy lifting in an asynchronous way, which doesn't seem to be the case here despite your use of the `async` keyword - the method body is lacking the `await` keyword and will run synchronously. `LoadPendingListFromLocalDb()` needs to return a Task to be awaitable. For the second problem, you should probably write a new question and provide more details.

Comment: Liyun Zhang - MSFT you are right, Frame makes problem on rendering. I was facing same, I resolved it by removing frame and making it async.

Comment: Glad to know you have resolved it and you can post your own answer or accepted my answer and this will help the other people who meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `ContentPage` has the `OnAppearing` method. It will be called every time when the page displays on the screen. So you can try to override the ContentPage's `OnAppearing` method to load the data that should show in the page.

In addition, if you want to load data when the app show on the screen not a special contentpage. You can override the [Cross-platform lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle#cross-platform-lifecycle-events).

Finally, you can try to override the platform's life cycle event. Such as you can override the MainActivity's `OnResume` method for the android.

For more information, you can refer to the official document about [App lifecycle in the .net maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle).

**Update:**

Please use the border in the maui instead of the frame. In addition, please use the `await` keyword when you call the async method.